# How to configure in mysql that works with following PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

Please tell me how to configure data in mysql so it can work with below mentioned PHP code.

I don't know what is $GYAZO_DB_PREFIX. in readme file they are telling it is // Database table prefix .

If it is Database table prefix  how to add it?

Also what is UserID & UserIP. They are fields or saprate tables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: you have to first give the username and password for the mysql database. Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you set `$GYAZO_DB_PREFIX = 'yourdb_'`,
 then, your table's name would be `yourdb_members`, `yourdb_table1`, etc. The DB prefix is usually configured by the user, or could be left blank, if your tables are going to be named `'members', 'table1'`, etc.

**UserID** & **UserIP** are both columns in the table `yourdb_members`.
You are trying to store UserID and UserIP in that table. If the userid exists, you are updating UserIP.

As @Truth said, **mysql_** functions are going to be deprecated soon, so refrain from using them.

Comment: Thanks for help.i got a solution. This should be closed now.